# Merging files recorded at different times (Adobe Audition)

Tags: sound-design, sound-effects, adobe-audition

I had to record the second part of my podcast after the first part was recorded. However, I noticed that the two parts sound differently (although recorded on the same computer with the same equipment). Is there any way to fix it and make the parts sound similar when putting them in one track? I tried to play with the volume but I still can hear the difference. And it can be seen in the picture that the amplitude of Number 1 is smaller than that of Number 2. [image]

Answer (score 1):

In general, you can't edit sound by looking at pictures.
There's a general indication that the 2nd take is pictorially more… 'dense', but that's all anyone can say about the difference. Maybe putting the files up on Soundcloud or similar may help us help you.

One rule of multiple disparate takes is to warm your voice first; that way it starts to sound more even. If you just bowl up to the mic & go for it in a single take, your voice will change over time. Trying to drop in on that on another day is not going to exhibit the same characteristics, even if you get the mic setup identical.

Depending on how disparate the two sound, you probably have two or three things to fix. For most of these, I'd first split the sound out to two tracks & run parallel or disparate processes.

1. The ambience against original signal. If the mic distances were different, or if for some reason they were not recorded in the same space with the same setup, then I'd try to remove the ambiences from both, then replace the whole lot with an artificial space.
   The only app I know that is really good at killing ambiences is Izotope RX. A tight, quiet room you can put back with just about any reverb.
2. The EQ. This might be possible to match. I'd really need to hear the two sources first.
   There are EQ-matching plugins, but I don't have much experience with them.
3. Volume/compression levels. If one is simply louder than the other, you can volume match with little effort. If, however, one is more heavily compressed than the other, then I'd be tempted to get a multi-band comp on *both*, with different settings. You're just going to have to do this by ear, but you might be able to either match the comp of the least compressed, or you could re-comp the pair to similar levels. If this is going for any kind of 'talk radio' type final output, then it's probably something you should do with the voice track anyway. Check output with a LUFS meter to make sure you keep within broadcast standards.

Answer (score 0):

Try putting the two audio files in a DAW, and increasing the gain on track 1. Gain (i.e. volume) affects amplitude. It looks like it's just a little low, so monitor the track levels as you bump the gain until they reach parity (are equal). After they sound about right, level wise, slightly fade out part one and fade in part 2 to reduce the chance of the audio "popping". Finally, add a limiter to the master track (which will be the combination of both). The limiter is important.

Increasing gain might introduce background hiss, if this is the case, just turn the gain on both tracks down.

If you wanted to get fiddly with it, you could use an equalizer to add a slight shelf on the high end, and use the bell to dip the really heinous parts. You can also use a multi-band compressor or even a de-esser for this. There's many ways to mitigate this, but probably impossible to remove it completely.

Comment: You could also just send me the files, I could do it, and write down the steps I took.